# multiple attribute database design

Tags: php, database

I have a product that has many color variants and I need some help to design the database tables. It's the same product but not all models have the same color variants. One product has 3 color and other may have 6 colors.

Comment: Hi, Bob, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”. You have to try before ask...

Comment: You can have table `products`, table `options` and table `option_to_product` where you tie a product ID to option ID

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you going. You can have price field in both, `models` and `options` then sum it in your script, that way you can have different price depending on model and color option.

[image]

## UPDATE

Your query will be somoething like:

```
SELECT
p.name AS 'product',
m.name AS 'model',
m.description AS 'model_description',
o.name AS 'option'
FROM `products` AS p

LEFT JOIN `models` AS m
ON (p.ID = m.product_id)

LEFT JOIN `option_to_model` AS otm
ON (m.ID = otm.model_id)

LEFT JOIN `options` AS o
ON (otm.option_id = o.ID)
```

Here is a live example for you [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38c18/2)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, The option_to_model table how is going to work with the different color variants? I don't need any price it is not an e-shop just product choices.